# how can I install Percona Server on Red Hat Community version i.e. on Fedora?

Tags: percona, fedora-21

Currently I am working on Fedora 21. I want to install Percona server but it seems it does not support for community version. Is there any workaround for this??

Comment: I don't know anything about Percona Server, but do note that while Fedora is sponsored by Red Hat and is the upstream for Red Hat Enterprise Linux, it is not in any way a "Red Hat [Enterprise Linux] Community Version".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be fine to download the RPMs from Percona.com

https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.7/Percona-Server-5.7.11-4/binary/redhat/6/x86_64/Percona-Server-5.7.11-4-r5c940e1-el6-x86_64-bundle.tar

Untar the archive and perform the install using YUM so that Fedora can satisfy any dependencies;

`bash-4.3# cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)`

`bash-4.3# yum install -y Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64.rpm Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64.rpm Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

`bash-4.3# rpm -qa | grep -i percona
Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64
Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.11-4.1.el6.x86_64`

Comment: Thanks @eroomydna ,I could able to install now